# Set the selected option in drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 Dropdown List made using Select Option Element. In one list I am inserting manually data while in the other two I am getting Data from Ajax.

My Question is that I want to make specific option to be selected by default. It is successfully applied in the first list but when I try to apply the code in other 2 list it doesn't get affected.

Code Snippet

```
<select id="box1">...</select>
<select id="box2">...</select>
<select id="box3">...</select>
```

Ajax Success Callback for box2 to insert options

```
success: function(data){
  modalFloorData = data;
  $("#demo2").attr("disabled",false);                         
  $("#demo2").html("<option value=''>Select Any Floor</option>");
  for(var i=0; i< data.length;i++){
      $("#box2").append("<option value='"+data[i].id+"''>"+data[i].name+"</option>");
  }
}
```

When I triggered Click Event on Button

```
$(".editBtn").on("click",function(e){
    var demoName1 = "value1";
    var demoName2 = "value2";
    var demoName3 = "value3";

        //Ajax Code for fetching Data for the 2 Dropdown List box2 & box 3
        //In box1 I am inserting options manually.

    $("#box1 option[value='"+demoName1+"']").attr("selected","selected");//Getting Success
    $("#box2 option[value='"+demoName2+"']").attr("selected","selected");
    $("#box3 option[value='"+demoName3+"']").attr("selected","selected");
    return false;
});
```

Any help would be appreciated...!!

Comment: Post together ajax code and the relevant html structure

Comment: Set the value in `ajax` success call back.

Comment: @Azim : please share the code snippet. Thank you.

Comment: @HarshKanakhara how do you expect to share "the code snippet" if you do not provide the ajax call he needs to adapt? We need your ajax javascript, and your html.

Comment: Share you `ajax` first. @HarshKanakhara

Answer (score 0):

You should set the value in ajax success call back. Because ajax is asynchronous. So values are setting before loading dropdown. Also you can use `val()` instead of `attr()` to set selected value.

```
$(".editBtn").on("click", function (e) {
    var demoName1 = "value1";
    var demoName2 = "value2";
    var demoName3 = "value3";

    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        type: '...',
        data: '...',
        success: function (result) {
            //do your stuff
            //.....
            //.....

            $("#box2").val(demoName2);
            $("#box3").val(demoName3);
        }
    })

    $("#box1").val(demoName1);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Nothing Happend. I tried your Code but it is displaying black value on the top. Please help.

Comment: I don't how are you trying. Set value at the very last of `success` callback. @HarshKanakhara